# Comparison between parameters of Dynatrace java monitoring and all jvm parameters

Tags: parameters, jvm

I want to do jvm monitoring programmatically. JConsole captures some of the jvm parameters. Does anybody have knowledge about parameters captured by DynaTrace java monitoring. And how those parameters are similar or disimilaer to jvm parameters.

DynaTrace java monitoring
https://www.dynatrace.com/technologies/java-monitoring/
 
List of JVM parameters
http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/#

Java version on my system is **1.7.0_76**

Comment: With a package to do it for you, you have to write code to trace actions so the information about them can be combined to get an end to end picture. Nothing magical about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about command line parameters that are passed to the JVM then the answer is YES. Dynatrace captures the full JVM parameter list. You can see all parameters if you open the Agnets Overview DAshlet. Click on one of the agents and you see all agent specific information in the details pane. this also includes information about the JVM itself, version, OS, platform, memory settings and the full command line parameter list

Andi